# running jenkins behind apache2 on subdomain and different port

Tags: apache, jenkins

I am attempting to get a jenkins instance (running on `http://localhost:8080/`) to be visible at `http://ci.domain.com:80/`.
Current status:
* Browsing to `ci.domain.com` gives me the content of domain.com
* Browsing to `ci.domain.com:8080` shows jenkins
* Browsing to `domain.com:8080` shows jenkins
Ideal status:
* Browsing to `ci.domain.com` shows jenkins
* Browsing to `ci.domain.com:8080` redirects to `ci.domain.com`
* Browsing to `domain.com:8080` does whatever the server would do if there were nothing running on port 8080

My current apache site config (working as expected for shifting traffic to HTTPS) is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName ci.domain.com
    ServerAlias ci
    Redirect temp / http://ci.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ci.domain.com
    ServerAlias ci

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode
    <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com

        <Directory /var/www/domain.com/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml $
        </IfModule>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml_php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the current output of `sudo netstat -nap | grep tcp | grep LISTEN | grep 80`

Comment: @DusanBajic `tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1903/apache2` The 80 is colored red if that's of any concern.

Comment: Is your Jenkins up and running?

Comment: Yes and I'm able to access it.